# Ternary operator with a null in 2nd value

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

Suppose, an `if statement` is like following

```
if(true) { doSomething() }
```

and I will write it as

```
true ? doSomething() : null
```

The result is same in both but there must be a difference in the purpose of both.

Could someone share their experience about

- what difference does `null` make . Is it a bad practice ?
- Is it future proof code because if I have to add a functionality in the future for an opposite case. I can just replace `null`rather writing a complete `else statement`

> PS: It does not make a big difference to write an `else case` either. So I hope answers or comments are not related to that.

Comment: Be aware that - in javascript - if you have `var x = 0, y = 0` then later do `x = (y==1 ? 1:null)` it would not ignore null, but set x to null.

Comment: Java or JavaScript? They are not the same. They are actually *very* different. What you show is not even valid in Java, since `value ? doSomething() : null` is not a *statement*.

Comment: `java !== javascript`, please add which language you need.

Comment: I was talking about javascript - edited

Comment: Yeah, but is OP asking about JavaScript, Java, or Groovy? Because the answer is very different, depending on the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator is not an *alternative* to `if` (in many aspects). Even though you can write all sorts of hacks that imitate other kinds of code, I can't imagine any competent programmer would even think of using ternary here instead of the normal, perfectly readable and working if clause.

It should be noted that the ternary operator isn't a very powerful tool. It can allow you to write some code in a shorter way sometimes, but that's hardly a reason to try to use it everywhere possible.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly my question. If we can do one thing two ways. why space out one (?:) unless other way has a different purpose(if)

Comment: We can usually do one thing in many ways. It doesn't mean all of them are smart ways, even though they may end up with the same results.

Answer (score 3):

`if` is a *statement*, a list of steps without an inherent value.

`a ? b : c` is an *expression* - it evaluates to the value of either `b` or `c`.

**The ternary operator works well** where you want to use the result of a conditional:

```
// After this line, `result` has either the return value of `doSomething` or `null`.
const result = value ? doSomething() : null
```

**`if` works well** where you don't need to use the result, you want to run several statements in any conditional branch or you want to chain several `if/else if/else` conditions.

[In most languages](http://phpsadness.com/sad/30) You can chain ternary expressions them to mimic `if/else if/else`, but that can be quite hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond that:

```
true ? doSomething() : null
```

will simply *surprise* most readers; no matter what programming language is used.

In that sense: this is a good example for a "bad" style; that is not helping the readability/clearness of your source code. Surprising your readers (in that sense) isn't a good idea:

[image: wtf-per-minute]